# Python email module can't handle quotes

Tags: python-3.x, email

I'm trying to use the email module to send emails. I'm getting the text body of the email by reading from a `txt` file. Everything works until I add quotes (both double and singles) to my text file, where the whole thing just gets screwed up

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

text1 = str(open('text1.txt').read())
msg1 = MIMEMultipart()
msg1.attach(MIMEText(text1))
print(text1)
print(msg1)

text2 = str(open('text2.txt').read())
msg2 = MIMEMultipart()
msg2.attach(MIMEText(text2))
print(text2)
print(msg2)
```

The results:

```
can parse this
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============8027747689981589951=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============8027747689981589951==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

can parse this
--===============8027747689981589951==--

cannot parse this ’
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============8498717586203770272=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============8498717586203770272==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Y2Fubm90IHBhcnNlIHRoaXMg4oCZ

--===============8498717586203770272==--
```

This is also a problem when I read username and password from `txt` files which have quotes in them, in which case I get this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/nathan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/CEP/Y3/RIPB Offence Booking System/OffenceBookingClasses.py", line 95, in WeeklyEmail
    self.EmailHandler.SendEmail('weekly', identifier='3A')
  File "/Users/nathan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/CEP/Y3/RIPB Offence Booking System/OffenceBookingClasses.py", line 365, in SendEmail
    self._SubSendEmail(teacher_email, text, attachment_filename)
  File "/Users/nathan/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/CEP/Y3/RIPB Offence Booking System/OffenceBookingClasses.py", line 390, in _SubSendEmail
    server.login(self.fromaddr, self.pw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 629, in auth
    response = encode_base64(initial_response.encode('ascii'), eol='')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position [a number is here but I'm removing it in case someone guesses my password from this]: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code for sending the email (this isn't a problem if I just use `str` variables in the code itself):

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(self.fromaddr, self.pw)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(self.fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The single quote next to “cannot parse this” looks like a Unicode smart single quote, rather than an ASCII apostrophe.

The Python mime module is therefore encoding it using Base64 encoding as it’s outside the range 32-128 in ASCII.

Which text editor are you using, as you might want to try an alternative?

Comment: I’m using TextEdit on my Mac with plain text mode turned on